# Menu help syntax of a program

Tags: c, linux, manpage

Are there some rules or pattern on how to write the terminal help menu of a program on linux?

Usually I use these arguments: `-?` or `-h` or `-H` to display the help of my program but is there a rule about that as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output for `--help` is not really a menu, just a help message.

There are some coding rules, in particular the [GNU coding standards](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#g_t_002d_002dhelp) specify something about `--help` (and also `--version`). I strongly suggest supporting both of them; as a user, I am pissed off by the few programs not understanding `--help`.

And the GNU libc provides several ways for providing that `--help`. I suggest looking into [argp](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html), but you could use [getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html#Getopt).